# Android Data Binding Error:Execution failed java.lang.RuntimeException:

Tags: java, android, data-binding

I tried to do some analog of example from here:
http://www.mutualmobile.com/posts/using-data-binding-api-in-recyclerview
And everything works correct except image url binding. I received error:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
>   ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app.imageUrl' with parameter type java.lang.String. file:D:\Projects\app\src\main\res\layout\view_simple_item.xml loc:43:32 - 43:47 ****\ data binding error ****

My Layout:

```
...
<data>       
    <variable
        name="item"
        type="com.example.Item" />
</data>
...

<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_item"
            app.imageUrl="@{item.imageUrl}"
            ... />
...
```

My adapter:

```
package com.example.adapters;

import android.databinding.BindingAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class CustomBindingAdapter {
    @BindingAdapter("bind:imageUrl")
    public static void loadImage(ImageView imageView, String url) {
        Picasso.with(imageView.getContext()).load(url).into(imageView);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know I'm late, but just drop the "bind:" and make it: @BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
that's how I add custom ones and works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my problem. Instead of:

```
app.imageUrl="@{item.imageUrl}"
```

Must be:

```
app:imageUrl="@{item.imageUrl}"
```

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: `app COLON` instead of `app DOT` Don't worry. I looked at this for 10 minutes until I was cross eyed.

Comment: won't compile for me says it can't find CustomBindingAdapter .imageUrl

Answer (score 0):

Set the argument of BindingAdapter annotation to "app:imageUrl". So you must have this:

```
@BindingAdapter("app:imageUrl")
```

instead of this:

```
@BindingAdapter("bind:imageUrl")
```

And also what @Alexander Myznikov said - change `app.imageUrl` to `app:imageUrl`

Answer (score 0):

Only try to rename the reference inside of the @BindingAdapter

```
@BindingAdapter({"bind:image_url"})
    public static void loadImage(ImageView imageView, String url) {
        Picasso.with(imageView.getContext()).load(url).into(imageView);
    }
```

And in your layout this:

```
...
<data>       
    <variable
        name="item"
        type="com.example.Item" />
</data>
...

<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_item"
            app:image_url="@{item.imageUrl}"
            ... />
...
```