# Android plugin 3.0.0+ data binding error?

Tags: java, android

build.gradle

```
compile 'me.tatarka.bindingcollectionadapter:bindingcollectionadapter:1.3.0'
compile 'me.tatarka.bindingcollectionadapter:bindingcollectionadapter-recyclerview:1.3.0'
```

Android plugin:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
```

Error:

```
Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'bind:itemView' with parameter type me.tatarka.bindingcollectionadapter.ItemView on android.widget.ListView.
file:E:\Work\*****\src\main\res\layout\activity_select_item.xml
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40228353/6016830 this may help.