# ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:image_url' with parameter type java.lang.String on android.widget.ImageView

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin

Getting stuck imageview databindig below are my custom adapter and Imageview. I refer to this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40188894/cannot-find-the-setter-for-attribute-with-parameter] but not getting solution - can anyone help? Thanks.

```
@BindingAdapter("app:image_url")
fun loadImage(view: ImageView, logoUrl: String?) {
    if (logoUrl == null) {
        view.setImageResource(R.drawable.alert_dark_frame)
    } else {
        Picasso.with(view.getContext())
            .load(logoUrl)
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.sym_def_app_icon)
            .into(view)
    }
}

<data>
    <import type="android.view.View" />
    <variable name="abc"
              type="com.example.viewmodel.Result"/>
</data>

<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/circleImageView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            app:image_url="@{abc.picture.thumbnail}"
            />
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove `app:` from the binding adapter?

Comment: yes i tried but not working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is normal error because the class `ImageView` doesn't contain a method `setImageUrl`, so you need to do a workaround for that by creating a class that `extends ImageView` and contains a method named `setImageUrl` that takes a `String` as parameter and set the image inside that method using `Picasso` library:

```
public class MyImageView extends ImageView {

    // ... here is the constructors
    public void setImageUrl(String url) {
        Picasso.get().load(url).into(this);
    }
}
```

and after that you can use it in the xml like this:

```
<com.yourPackage.MyImageView
    android:id="@+id/circleImageView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:image_url="@{abc.picture.thumbnail}"
    />
```

Comment: the one way which i found is i use picasso in onBindViewHolderlike below ( i know this is not right way )       Picasso.with(c)
                .load(holder.binding.abc!!.picture.medium)
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)                                                    It solve my problem for temp.
                .into(holder.binding.circleImageView)

Comment: i thought that when we create custom attributes to widgets, we only need to declare BindingAdapter or InverseBindingAdapter. it seems we also need to extend the widget itself as a class and declare those get/set methods?

Answer (score 12):

Can you try adding the plugin in your build.gradle (app) file

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Comment: By using this  i got issue in Data-binding generated classes

Comment: What's the issue which you are getting?

Comment: sorry for the late reply  i am getting this error after using kotlin-kapt plugin  ActivityMain2Binding(DataBindingComponent _bindingComponent, View _root,
                                 ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class ActivityMain2Binding

Comment: I got a problem about this, and I add apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' this in my build.gradle,works fine. before I add this line , it don't even generate @BindingAdapter attr in whole project.thanks very much

Answer (score 3):

I just changed from

> app:srcCompat

to

> android:src

in my case when using it together with databinding.Working fine now.Hope this helps.

**OLD CODE**

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/avenir_roman"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                app:srcCompat="@{model.image}"/>
```

**NEW CODE**

```
  <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/avenir_roman"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                    android:src="@{model.image}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Write the following code in the model class

```
 companion object DataBindingAdapter {
        @BindingAdapter("bind:image_url")
        @JvmStatic
        fun loadImage(imageView: ImageView, image_url: String) {
            Picasso.get().load(image_url).fit()
                    .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)        
                    .into(imageView)        }
    }
```

In XML write the following code

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/movie_image"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.027"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:image_url="@{movieList.component5()}"/>
```