# Can't find setter for view that accepts parameter and Resource Linking Failed

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-binding-adapter

I am stuck in binding adapter. Following adapter is not working and it looks like that IDE is having trouble in finding this adpater. I have tried many solutions, but all in vain.

I tried all of answers provided in this question, but nothing worked:
[Cannot find the setter for attribute with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40188894/cannot-find-the-setter-for-attribute-with-parameter)

**Note:** I have another adapter to load image in same file, and it is working fine.

What I want to achieve is simply, whenever user enters the characters in some editText, if that editText has destination specified, then request focus of destination after character count reaching to limit.

**Binding Adapter**

```
@BindingAdapter(value = ["destination","limit"])
fun moveToNext(editText: EditText, dest: EditText, limit:Int) {
    editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {

        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            if (count == limit) {
                dest.requestFocus()
            }
        }

    })
}
```

**in .xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.eshaafi.eshaafi.ui.auth.mobile_verification.MobileVerificationViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_512"
            android:transitionName="sharedLogo"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.35"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/logoText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="e s h a a f i"
            android:textColor="@color/colorLogoBlue"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:transitionName="sharedLogoText"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/logo"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.12"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/logo"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/logo" />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="Wait for verification code"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="You will soon receive verification code on"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mobileNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@={viewModel.mobileNumber}"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/digit_1"
            style="@style/CodDigitEditText"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/digit2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mobileNumber"
            destination="@{digit2}"
            limit="1"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/digit2"
            style="@style/CodDigitEditText"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/digit_3"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/digit_1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/digit_1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/digit_3"
            style="@style/CodDigitEditText"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/dash"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/digit2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/digit_1" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/dash"
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@color/colorGrey"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/digit_4"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/digit_3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/digit_1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/digit_1"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/digit_4"
            style="@style/CodDigitEditText"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/digit_5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/dash"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/digit_1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/digit_5"
            style="@style/CodDigitEditText"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/digit_6"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/digit_4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/digit_1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/digit_6"
            style="@style/CodDigitEditText"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/digit_5"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/digit_1"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>


        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btnContinue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="64dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:alpha="0"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="Continue"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorWhite"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**Errorr**

`Cannot find a setter for <android.widget.EditText destination> that accepts parameter type 'android.widget.EditText'`

Comment: can you paste your whole xml file for better understanding?

Comment: Suggestion regardless of this issue

            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/digit2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mobileNumber"

in above code you are refering digit2 and mobileNumber which is alread added id. so you should use it as below:
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/digit2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/mobileNumber"

Comment: I updated question and added full layout file.

Comment: @PVartak your suggestion didn't made any difference

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out on my own, that the problem was not with passing EditText, but the other parameter

**Before**

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/digit_1"
            style="@style/CodDigitEditText"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/digit2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mobileNumber"
            destination="@{digit2}"
            limit="1"
            />
```

Notice, the value of `limit=1`, and this was the problem, I simply changed it to `limit="@{1}"` and the error was gone

**After**

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/digit_1"
            style="@style/CodDigitEditText"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/digit2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mobileNumber"
            destination="@{digit2}"
            limit="@{1}"
            />
```